# How many four-digit numbers contain only the digits 1 and 2 and each of them at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

Question: How many four-digit numbers contain only the digits 1 and 2 and each of them at least once?

I have tried to do this question by listing all the possible values and have come to answer of 14. So, I was wondering whether there is a more efficient method instead of listing all the possible values.

Thank you.

Comment: There are $2^4$ total 4-digit sequences containing only 1s or 2s (for each digit you have two choices). 2 of them are only 1's or only 2's. So subtract them off

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when a question has an accepted answer 22 minutes after it was asked...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because unless it is reworded to apply to the general situation, it is not going to be of future relevance to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $2^4-2 = 14$.  The first term indicates the way of choosing four independent digits, each one having two possibilities (being either $1$ or $2$); the $-2$ takes out $1111$ and $2222$.

Comment: Is the 2^4 like a formula I need to remember to solve questions like this?

Answer (score 2):

The number of 4-digit numbers with only digits $1$ and $2$ is $2^4=16$, and 2 of them are $1111$ and $2222$, which should be excluded.

Comment: How did you get 2^4? Is it some sort of formula?

Comment: I suppose.  If you have $n$ choices to make, and each one has $k$ possibilities, then there are $k$ ways to make the first choice, $k$ ways to make the second choice, etc.  If they're all independent (as they are in this case), the number of ways to make all $n$ choices is $k$ times $k$ times ... $k$ ($n$ times), or $k^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your support.